# FuelSDK Python ET_Subscriber using SubscriberID in props

Tags: api, fuel-sdk

According to the documentation [HERE](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/subscribers/subscriber-retrieve.html), I should be able to explicitly specify fields in the 'props' which limits my results to only those columns.  This appears to work until I add 'ID' (which is specified in the list of available values).  Doing so results in all fields being returned.

I am using the FuelSDK-Python.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
########################################################################
from FuelSDK import *
########################################################################
debug = False

stubObj = ET_Client(False, debug) 

getSubscriber = ET_Subscriber()

getSubscriber.auth_stub = stubObj

getSubscriber.props = ["ID","SubscriberKey","EmailAddress"]

getResponse = getSubscriber.get()

print getResponse.results
########################################################################
```

Any help here is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I ended up opening a support case with ET, the result of which is that this is behaving as intended.  I suggested the documentation be updated to provide the proper expectation.  That documentation has yet to be updated...

Answer (score 0):

Response from ET Support:

"You have encountered one of the fringe cases when it comes to requesting properties via the API. Almost every other property requires a specific request for it to be returned. However, when requesting ID on the subscriber object, the subscriberID is returned, along with all of the profile attributes In fact, this is the only way I have been able to retrieve profile attributes in my own tests."